# django RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error while creating

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

models:

```
    class FullNameMixin(models.Model):
        name_id    = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True, unique=False, default=None, blank=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
        last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)


        class Meta:
            abstract = True

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'fullname'


    class User(FullNameMixin):
        id        = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
        username  = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        email     = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        token     = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
        password  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        role      = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        verified  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
        updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username    

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'cga_user'


    class Profile(FullNameMixin):
        id                  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
        birthday            = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        country             = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        state               = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        postcode            = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        phone               = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        profession_headline = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        image               = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
        profile_banner      = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path_banner, null=True, blank=True)
        cga_user            = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
        gender              = models.CharField(
                                max_length=255, blank=True, default="", choices=USER_GENDER_CHOICES
                            )
        created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
        updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'profile'
```

When i am creating Profile from django admin panel getting below error.

```
    e
        filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/africa/backend/api/model_utils/utils.py", line 7, in get_upload_path
        instance.user,
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/africa/backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 421, in __get__
        raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
    api.models.FullNameMixin.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Profile has no user.
    [24/Jul/2021 13:49:51] "POST /admin/api/profile/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 199997
```

please take a look how can i fix this.
Note: User model creation working but, profile not working

I checked in drf and django admin panel .
both place not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are declaring a User model which is in fact just a model. That's not how it works.
The User is a special type of model and if you want to change it you have to extend the AbstractUser class.
Alternatively you can connect to it via one-to-one classes in the classic user-profiles approach.

But here you are creating a user model that (besides using the reserved word 'User') has none of the requirements necessary to be treated as a user who can be authenticated and that can instantiate sessions.

[> Example of a simple user-profiles architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002498/django-multiple-user-model/65003375#65003375)

[> Working with User objects - Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) (i particularly recommend this one)

I would recommend you to read-up on django user authentication.