# django how should I create my multiple user

Tags: django, django-models

I have two different users, one requesting for repairs (Office) and the inspector/repairman which is (Technician). I was wondering if this is a good idea to make both officeid/techid in customUser like this or there's a better way

[image]

this is the values of both office and technician, We have hr/accounting for example then EMP-**

[image]

this is my full erd so far I might change somethings based on your recommendations

[image]

Edit: I also thinking of adding similar to this, incase I create like IT support requesting aircon maintenance from machine office or something

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
```

Comment: Does this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002498/django-multiple-user-model] answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about inheriting user class?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Technican(AbstractUser):
    techName = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    
class Office(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    head = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=_('Head'))
```

Or if you have custom fields that are mutual for both user types, then create first your own base user class and inherit that to Technican and Office.