# Creating relationship between Student and Class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am trying to create models where I can have a relationship between Students and ClassName tables so that I can get all users using ClassName.objects.get() and ClassName using the Student.objects.get() method.
I am completely stuck here.
Should I add more fields to the Student model?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class ClassName(models.Model):
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    section = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.grade} - {self.section}"


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, null=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124, default=f"{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}")
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    national_id= models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    student_class = models.ForeignKey(ClassName, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name}"
```

I am trying to find a method to get all users using ClassName.objects.get() and ClassName using the Student.objects.get() method.

Comment: to get all callsses, use ClassName.objects.all() and for all student  Student.objects.all().   get is use to fetch a single object, eg:  Student.objects.get(pk=1).  Also your Student model can be improved by using the User model, check it, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: what is the use case of this ClassName model

Comment: Do You mean, get all student with classname model.  If like this, try like `ClassName.objects.filter(name={Writeclassname here}).prefetch_related("student_set")` and you can use with classname.student, it return list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like what you're trying to set up is a `many-to-many` (m2m) relationship between users and classes. That makes sense because a user is enrolled in multiple classes and each class is attended by multiple students.

Then you decided to create your own user models, this also makes sense as it opens the door to possible future changes to the codebase without having to perform risky manual operations on the DB.

You extended `AbstractUser`. Now spend a minute to go check in the Django codebase what attributes and methods does `AbstractUser` comes with:
[>> AbstractUser <<](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L334)

You can see that it comes with `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `is_staff`, `is_active`, etc.. So this is all already built-in in Django, if you use this model as base (as you should) you don't need to re-declare all these attributes.

Now ask yourself: How many students each user can represent? Normally the answer to that should be "just 1", so this tells you that between user and student you probably want a `one-to-one` relationship.

So, to recap, you need a `User` model with a 1to1 relationship with a `Student` model, then you need a m2m relationship between `Student` and `ClassName`. Let's see how to implement it:

```
# User and Student
class User(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, default='')
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    national_id= models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
```

Now you probably noticed how some fields are missing from your original implementation and how I moved some others from `Student` to `User`.

I didn't include some of the fields that already exist in the `AbstractUser` model that you inherit when declaring `User`, because you already have access to those. So if for example you were to execute:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1) 
print(user.first_name)
```

This would work fine.

The reason why i moved the `Student` fields into `User` is because those are attributes that belong to the `User`. If for example you wanted to store `average_grade` then it would squarely belong in the `Student` model.
For example `father_name` probably belongs in the `Student` model. Let's say that later you want to add a `Teacher` model, I can't imagine it being mandatory for teachers to provide their father's name. But i'll let you decide that! For more information on this you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002498/django-multiple-user-model/65003375#65003375) i wrote sometime back about this specific model structure you're trying to implement.

Now let's look at the m2m relationship between `Student` and `ClassName`.
For this i really recommend you to read some introductory material on databases and on database relationships. Many-to-many relationships are the most difficult to wrap your head around and you may need to spend sometime doing that before you proceed with your Django project.

You can check out [this video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002498/django-multiple-user-model/65003375#65003375) for a summary of a lot of important database concepts. It has helped me in the past.

Here is how you would implement it:

```
class Student(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
    class_names = models.ManyToManyField(ClassName, related_name="students")

class ClassName(models.Model):
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    section = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

I recommend you to read the very good [django docs on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to form an idea of what you can do with them.

In simple terms though, this means that every `Student` can have many `ClassName` and every `ClassName`s can have many `Student`s.

You can manipulate the relationship from both sides. For example:

```
class_name_1 = ClassName.objects.get(id=1)
class_name_2 = ClassName.objects.get(id=2)
user.class_names.add(class_name_1)
user.class_names.add(class_name_2)
print(user.class_names.all()). # will print: [class_name1, class_name2]

print(class_name_1.students.all()). # will print: [user, ]
```